# MySQL TimeStamp To Date/Time PHP: always 1/1/1 01:00

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp, jpgraph

I have to create an array with date/time of each row.
I am using the following code. "TIME_STAMP" is the field which contains MySQL Timestamp (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP default).

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
    $timestamp = strtotime($row["TIME_STAMP"]);
    $x[] = sprintf("%s, %s", date ('j/n', $timestamp), date('H:i', $timestamp));
}
```

If i make a SELECT * from mysql client all is ok: TIME STAMP is correct:

2013-06-04 17:11:43

but when I pass this array to JpGraph (to make horizontal axis) all the records are displayed with

1/1 01:00

The code for the graph:

```
$graph = new Graph("1024", "800");
$graph->SetScale( 'textlin');
$graph->img-> SetMargin(60,40,40,110);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels( $x );
$graph->xgrid->Show(true);
```

Any hint?

Comment: What do you get if you `echo $row["TIME_STAMP"];` directly before line 3?

Comment: give me blank....what's happening?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the column name of the table is `TIME_STAMP`?

Answer (score 1):

My guess here is that the value you're dealing with is a string, rather than an actual DateTime object.  You might want to create a new DateTime object with that string before passing it along to the next step.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php

Comment: This shouldn't be the issue, `strtotime` should be returning a valid timestamp which can be used as shown above. e.g.`$ts = strtotime('now + 1 day'); printf("%s, %s", date ('j/n', $ts), date('H:i', $ts));`

Comment: You got me!  I'm no PHP guy, but every time I think I'm dealing with a date (in JS) and it starts being the first day of epoch, I know my date isn't really a Date :)

Answer (score 1):

You have: 
$graph->SetScale( 'textlin');

it should be: 
$graph->SetScale( 'datlin');

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

My select query didn't include "TIME_STAMP" field; the graph was added later, but query wasn't updated with new attributes for JpGraph.

Thanks anyone for the help.

Comment: In this case, `$row["TIME_STAMP"]` should have triggered an *undefined index* notice. You need to configure PHP to report errors.

Comment: I am running on a hosted service (can't change conf.) anyway thanks for the hint that I wasn't know so far.

Comment: 1) You don't have to change the error reporting settings for the whole server. 2) Anyway, you shouldn't develop on the live site.